# Could not resolve all files for configuration :app:debugRuntimeClasspath

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, error-handling, dependencies

On React Native 0.64.1 after build project in Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 get the error:

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "+" // default: "+"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0" // default: "21.1.0"

        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    } 
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Android Gradle Plugin Version: 4.1.0
Gradle Version: 6.9-rc-1

What I tried:

1.Clean project => Rebuild project

2.Reinstall npm packages

3.Turn off the Toggle Offline Mode

4.Change SDK, NDK versions

But nothing works.

Comment: Was this fixed? I am currently encountering the same error

Comment: No, I could not find any good decision. Only change in build.gradle file the version of build gradle from 4.1.0 to 4.2.2:  classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0') => classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2')

Comment: Did it fixed the problem by that?

Comment: It is help to avoid this error, but not fix it

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your response :)